# how can i replace array value dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following arrays both's length and value will be dynamic

```
$one = array('11','12');
$two = array('0','0','0','0','1','1');
```

Want result like

```
$result = array('11','11','11','11','12','12');
```

Comment: so what are the merging rule? seems like no rule here..

Comment: and whats the login behind this?

Comment: number of occurrences in second array of indicies will result in copying the the elements of first array that many times. is the logic correct?

Comment: @JitendraParmar Hope my post will help you out..

Comment: yes its correct Yaman Jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using `array_map`, `array_unique` and `preg_replace` to actieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787501)

```
<?php
$one = array('11','12');
$two = array('0','0','0','0','1','1');

$search=array_map(function($value){
    return $value='/\b'.$value."\b/";
},array_unique($two)); //Here we are creating an array which we want to search

print_r(preg_replace($search, $one, $two));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 12
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($two as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$key] = $one[$value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
<?php
$one = array('11','12');
$two = array('0','0','0','0','1','1');

$result = array();
foreach($two as $i){
    $result[] = $one[(int) $i];
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sahil's answer is too inefficient.  Your desired output can be achieved much more efficiently with less code.

Input:

```
$one = array('11','12');
$two = array('0','0','0','0','1','1');
```

Method #1: `array_map()`

```
$result=array_map(function($v)use($one){return $one[$v];},$two));
var_export($result);
```

Method #2: `array_walk()`

```
array_walk($two,function($v)use($one,&$result){$result[]=$one[$v];});
var_export($result);
```

Method #3: `foreach()`

```
foreach($two as $v){
    $result[]=$one[$v];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output (regardless of method):

```
array (
  0 => '11',
  1 => '11',
  2 => '11',
  3 => '11',
  4 => '12',
  5 => '12',
)
```